# Trouble with the simplest regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to validate an ASP `TextBox` that can only have 1-2 digits (not zero) using the following regex:

```
^[1-9]{1,2}
```

This regex doesn't validate if the field is empty (assumed it would due to the 1-2 part)

Also tried  `^[1-9+]{1,2}` to no avail.

These are my controls:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInHour" 
             MaxLength="2" 
             runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Bind("InHour") %>' 
            Width="80"/>


<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rvInHour" 
                ControlToValidate="txtInHour" 
                Display="None" 
                ValidationExpression="^[1-9]{0,2}$" 
                runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="InHour is incorrectly formatted." />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that for some reason RegularExpressionValidators don't work when there's no input to match against (blank fields) so I had to use a seperate RequiredFieldValidator. Thanks for your input everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that you don't allow zeros in your pattern. So 10 or 20 is not valid? The second thing is that you start with "starts with" AKA "^" but there's no "ends with" AKA "$"

So.. try this:

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$
```

In human readable:

- starts with 1-9, followed by an optional digit from 0-9, end of string.

On the other hand I don't know what you've meant with ("no zeros") - no zeros at all?!

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering. I tried your solution but using this regex I can still leave the field empty and it's not getting validated

Comment: Well.. I have no clue about ASP.. But that PCRE-pattern is correct! Check your code logic!

Comment: I updated my question with my controls' markup. I don't quite see why your solution is not working, makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: It's indeed a problem with RegularExpressionValidator. I've added an answer that explains.

Comment: Ah.. I see. Thanks for the update! That way nobody misses the part. Regards, jan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex :

```
 ^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```